# How to remove or erase a "key":"value" pair in a Json::Value object using "key"?

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio, set, jsoncpp

I am working in C++ language, visual studio 2022, and using [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) library for working with Json.

To Give you an Idea, here is an example of Json data I am working with

```
[ 
    { 
        "name":"Regina Eagle",
        "job":"Biologist",
        "salary":"728148120",
        "email":"Regina_Eagle6155@y96lx.store",
        "city":"Nashville"
    },
    { 
        "name":"Julius Baker",
        "job":"Fabricator",
        "salary":"299380360",
        "email":"Julius_Baker9507@voylg.center",
        "city":"Las Vegas"
    },
    { 
        "name":"Rocco Sawyer",
        "job":"Chef Manager",
        "salary":"223764496",
        "email":"Rocco_Sawyer4620@qu9ml.club",
        "city":"San Francisco"
    },
    { 
        "name":"Chad Murray",
        "job":"Project Manager",
        "salary":"43031808",
        "email":"Chad_Murray6940@jcf8v.store",
        "city":"Bridgeport"
    },
    { 
        "name":"Rocco Parker",
        "job":"Lecturer",
        "salary":"322089172",
        "email":"Rocco_Parker202@ag5wi.solutions",
        "city":"Indianapolis"
    }
]
```

It's a Json array of objects (with key:value pairs).
I have a set of column heads for eg: {"name","job","salary"}, and I want to sort the json data in a way that each object will have only  columns that are in the given set.

This is my approach:

> Store json data in a Json::Value object (let us say records).

> Iterate through records (as it is an array).

> Creating another loop to Iterate through object stored at each index.

> Extract the key of the key:value pair and check if it's present in the set or not.

> If it's present then continue, else if it isn't then remove that key:value entry from there.

> This way we can delete unwanted column while looping through the object.

Here, is the code snippet:

```
set<string> col {"name","job","salary"};
Json::Value records = [ 
    { 
        "name":"Regina Eagle",
        "job":"Biologist",
        "salary":"728148120",
        "email":"Regina_Eagle6155@y96lx.store",
        "city":"Nashville"
    },
    { 
        "name":"Julius Baker",
        "job":"Fabricator",
        "salary":"299380360",
        "email":"Julius_Baker9507@voylg.center",
        "city":"Las Vegas"
    },
    { 
        "name":"Rocco Sawyer",
        "job":"Chef Manager",
        "salary":"223764496",
        "email":"Rocco_Sawyer4620@qu9ml.club",
        "city":"San Francisco"
    },
    { 
        "name":"Chad Murray",
        "job":"Project Manager",
        "salary":"43031808",
        "email":"Chad_Murray6940@jcf8v.store",
        "city":"Bridgeport"
    },
    { 
        "name":"Rocco Parker",
        "job":"Lecturer",
        "salary":"322089172",
        "email":"Rocco_Parker202@ag5wi.solutions",
        "city":"Indianapolis"
    }
];

for (int i = 0; i<records.size(); i++)
{
  for (auto j = records[i].begin(); j != records[i].end(); j++)
    {
      string key = j.key().asString();
      if (col.find(key) != col.end())
        {
          continue;
        }
      else
        {
          records[i].removeMember(key);
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine until the 'removeMember' function get to run, and throws an error saying can't increment the value of iterator.

> Expression: cannot increment value-initialized map/set iterator

Am I doing something wrong?

Or there is another/better way of doing this ?

Please advice.

Comment: _"Am I doing something wrong?"_: don't remove or add elements in a container you're currently iterating.

Comment: I don't know about this library but std::containers don't allow you to continue itterating  after you have removed an item, you have to restart the loop.

Comment: You can also use std::remove_if to remove all entries based on a predicate (function or lambda). [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).
Don't forget to call erase after remove_if. Which has the added benefit that it show in code what you are doing (instead of having an extra for loop)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Assuming `Json::Value` supports `std::remove_if` and `std::erase`.

Comment: But you could create your own "remove_if" / "erase". Iterate over `records[i]`, store the keys in a `std::vector`, iterate the `std::vector` and remove the properties.

Comment: @jabaa good point, I usually dont work on serialized data directly. I always convert it to C++ structures first. e.g std::vector<my_employee_type> and work on those. That keeps my business logic indpendent on the serialization technology. And it looks like Json::Value is a map and then indeed std::remove_if will not work.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I am reading Json data from files using streams, then saving it into Json::Value container ( from jsoncpp lib).Is there a better way to do it than what I am doing?

Comment: My feedback was about improving design by decoupling your data reading/writing from the actual data you work on. First you should have an employee interface, then you can derive an employee class. And lastly you can have a factory method that you pass your json file and which will return a std::vector<> of your interfaces. This method will read the data from json and you use it to create instances of your own employee class. The interface is there so you can also make some test mocks with prefilled employee data. But all this goes way outside the scope of your original question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't remove or add elements in a container you're currently iterating.

The JSON objects are stored in a `std::map` and `removeMember` calls `std::map::erase`. It invalidates the current iterator and it can't be incremented anymore. `j++` causes the error.

One approach is to first only store the keys of properties you want to delete, and then to delete the properties in a separate loop.

```
set<string> col {"name","job","salary"};
Json::Value records = [ 
    { 
        "name":"Regina Eagle",
        "job":"Biologist",
        "salary":"728148120",
        "email":"Regina_Eagle6155@y96lx.store",
        "city":"Nashville"
    },
    { 
        "name":"Julius Baker",
        "job":"Fabricator",
        "salary":"299380360",
        "email":"Julius_Baker9507@voylg.center",
        "city":"Las Vegas"
    },
    { 
        "name":"Rocco Sawyer",
        "job":"Chef Manager",
        "salary":"223764496",
        "email":"Rocco_Sawyer4620@qu9ml.club",
        "city":"San Francisco"
    },
    { 
        "name":"Chad Murray",
        "job":"Project Manager",
        "salary":"43031808",
        "email":"Chad_Murray6940@jcf8v.store",
        "city":"Bridgeport"
    },
    { 
        "name":"Rocco Parker",
        "job":"Lecturer",
        "salary":"322089172",
        "email":"Rocco_Parker202@ag5wi.solutions",
        "city":"Indianapolis"
    }
];

for (int i = 0; i<records.size(); i++)
{
  std::vector<std::string> toRemove;
  for (auto j = records[i].begin(); j != records[i].end(); j++)
    {
      string key = j.key().asString();
      if (col.find(key) != col.end())
        {
          continue;
        }
      else
        {
          // records[i].removeMember(key);
          toRemove.push_back(key);
        }
    }
  for (const auto &key : toRemove)
    {
      records[i].removeMember(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Include the necessary headers:

   #include 
   #include <json/json.h>